# Get named group subpattern from .NET regex object

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Let's say I have the following regex:

```
var r = new Regex("Space(?<entry>[0-9]{1,3})");
```

Then I have the string:

```
"Space123"
```

Here is my program:

```
void Main()
{
    Regex r = new Regex("Space(?<entry>[0-9]{1,3})", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    foreach (Match m in r.Matches("Space123")){
        m.Groups["entry"].Dump(); //Dump() is linqpad to echo the object to console
    }
}
```

What I want to know is if there is any way to to get the regular expression part that matched? In this case:

```
(?<entry>[0-9]{1,3})
```

I can't find it anywhere in the object, but one would think it would be accessible.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question... the regex expression that matches is the pattern you used `Space(?<entry>[0-9]{1,3})`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Right, but I want to get it out of the object, just the capture part, namely (<entry>[0-9]{1,3}), not the whole string.

Comment: As far as I know, regular expressions are usually implemented by building a state machine behind the scenes which parses the syntax and spits out a boolean result.  Therefore, a single regular expression is basically its own self-contained system.  The only way I can see to do what you want would be to make multiple smaller regular expressions and match them all against your text separately.

Comment: Given an arbitrary regular expression, which you don't know beforehand, you want to extract the regular expression in all the capturing groups? Is that your problem? There are 2 approaches: somehow parse the regular expression yourself (which is tricky to get it correct, unless you read the source code of .NET), **or** hook the private methods in RegexParser class (whose process I'm not sure is feasible or not).

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and explain what you're trying to achieve with this, before you start digging around with reflection and/or building your own regex parser..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leverage the [`Regex.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method that stores the regular expression pattern. Named capure groups and their respective indices can be obtained using [`Regex.GetGroupNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Regex.GetGroupNumbers()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnumbers(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, we need an array/list of the capture groups inside the regex pattern, that is why I am adding `rxPairedRoundBrackets` regex to capture all texts inside unescaped round brackets.

I suggest this code to get the regex subpattern for a specific *named* group (**edit**: now, even handling nested unescaped parenthetical groups!):

```
var rxPairedRoundBrackets = new Regex(@"(?sx)(?=((?<=[^\\]|^)\(
        (?>
          (?! (?<!\\)\( | (?<!\\)\) ) .
          |
          (?<!\\)\( (?<Depth>)
          |
          (?<!\\)\) (?<-Depth>)
        )*
        (?(Depth)(?!))
        (?<!\\)\)))+");
var r = new Regex(@"(?<OuterSpace>Spa(?<ce>ce))(?<entry>\([0-9]{1,3}\))", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var bracketedGrps = rxPairedRoundBrackets.Matches(r.ToString()).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value);
var GroupDict = r.GetGroupNames().Zip(r.GetGroupNumbers(), (s, i) => new { s, i })
                                 .ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);
foreach (Match m in r.Matches("My New Space(123)"))
{
    var id = "entry";
    var grp = m.Groups[id]; // Just to see the group value
    var groupThatMatched = bracketedGrps.ElementAt(GroupDict[id] - 1);
}
```

And here is the code for your case:

```
r = new Regex("Space(?<entry>[0-9]{1,3})", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
bracketedGrps = rxPairedRoundBrackets.Matches(r.ToString()).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value);
GroupDict = r.GetGroupNames().Zip(r.GetGroupNumbers(), (s, i) => new { s, i })
                             .ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);
foreach (Match m in r.Matches("Space123"))
{
   var id = "entry";
   var grp = m.Groups[id];
   var groupThatMatched = bracketedGrps.ElementAt(GroupDict[id] - 1);
}
```

Output:

[image]